# PHP/Laravel groupBy is extremely slow

Tags: php, laravel

Our customers pay for licenses that run for some time, e.g. 6 months.
Example:

```
Product: product1
Payment date: 2024-01-01
Start date: 2024-01-01
End date: 2024-03-31
Total excluding tax: $29.99
```

We want to know how much of this amount goes towards which month.
So we calculate the number of days (in this case: 31 + 29 + 31 = 91) and divide the amount by this number to get the amount per day ($29.99 / 91 days = $0.32956 / day), and then we get:

```
January 2024: 31 * $0.32956 = $10.216
February 2024: 29 * $0.32956 = $9.557
March 2024: 31 * $0.32956 = $10.216
```

Here, the numbers are very similar for the sake of the example, but usually, we'd of course have licenses that start in the middle of the month, so the numbers can be very different.

We have thousands of such licenses for different products, so it's a grouping both by product and by month, which would be very slow to do in the database (MariaDB).
For this reason, we want to do a single, simple SQL SELECT that fetches all licenses, and then do the grouping in PHP/Laravel code.
Yet for some reason, this is excruciatingly slow.
The code looks like this:

```php
    public function revenueWaterfall(Request $request)
    {
        $products = $request->get('product_id') == 'all' ? Products::all() : Product::whereId($request->get('product_id'))->get();

        $bookedPeriodTo = $request->get('bookedPeriodTo');
        $bookedPeriodFrom = $request->get('bookedPeriodFrom');

        $productId = $products->count() == 1 ? $products->first()->id : null;

        $allData = Invoice::getAllForPeriod(Carbon::parse($bookedPeriodFrom), Carbon::parse($bookedPeriodTo), $productId)->groupBy('product_id')->sort();

        $splitValues = $allData->map(function ($productPayments) {
                    $total = $productPayments->sum('total_excluding_tax');
                    $months = $this->splitRevenueByMonth($productPayments);
                    return array_merge($months, ['total' => $total]);
                });
        return response()->json($splitValues);
    }

    function splitRevenueByMonth($payments)
    {
        $byMonth = [];

        foreach ($payments as $payment) {
            $startDay = Carbon::parse($payment->period_start)->startOfDay();
            $endDay = Carbon::parse($payment->period_end)->startOfDay();
            $daysInPeriod = $endDay->diffInDays($startDay);

            if ($daysInPeriod < 1) {
                // Handle invalid period
                throw new \Exception("Invalid period detected");
            }

            $amountPerDay = $payment->total_excluding_tax / $daysInPeriod;

            for ($i = clone $startDay; $i->lessThan($endDay); $i->addDay()) {
                $month = $i->format('M Y');
                $byMonth[$month] = ($byMonth[$month] ?? 0) + $amountPerDay;
            }
        }

        return $byMonth;
    }
```

Actually, when I look at the code now (I slightly simplified it for the sake of this question), it seems like the grouping by product is missing.
What we would like to have is an output like this:

```json
{
"product1":
    {
        "January 2024": 2255209.2525,
        "February 2024: 5252525.5336,
        "March 2024": 35363.3636
    },
"product2":
    {
        "December 2023": 309906.3532,
        "January 2024": 3059035.9092
    }
}
```

etc.

Comment: `$months = $this->splitRevenue($productPayments);` - was this supposed to be `splitRevenueByMonth`, or do you have an additional method `splitRevenue`?

Comment: @CBroe Sorry, fixed. It was supposed to be splitRevenueByMonth. I slightly modified the code for the question.

Comment: Looping over every single day in the date range is probably not the most performant thing to do, especially with Carbon adding additional overhead on the clone and addDay operations. I'd go with a bit more math & logic here. For all _full_ months in the date interval, you know the amount of days (resp., you can easily determine it.) No need to loop over 31 individual days for January, when you can simply do `31 * $amountPerDay` instead.

Comment: And for the first and last month, which might only be partially covered, you need to determine the difference between the start month day and the last day of that month, and for the last month you got the number of days already.

Comment: @CBroe Sure, that's possible, but that would also add a lot of overhead: I would have to find all the months in the period, find out if it's a "full" or "partial" month, determine the correct number of days, etc. It's not trivial. The current implementation is MUCH simpler, and it's SUPER fast in C#. I don't understand why it's so slow in PHP/Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

Have you been able to confirm the code bottleneck? I see a couple spots that I would investigate. I know you're focused on the grouping, but maybe check out these areas as well.

1. `$allData = Invoice::getAllForPeriod(...)`: The grouping and sorting directly from the DB call should be timed to ensure it's not slow here. A DB index could be helpful.
2. Inside your `.map` statement you are using `$total = $productPayments->sum('total_excluding_tax');` That is totaling all of the payments for the given product, but then the `splitRevenueByMonth` looks at every payment for that product again. Try calculating `$total` inside `splitRevenueByMonth` and returning that as part of your response. You're already looping through the entire range of the `$payment`, so you can calculate the total as you go. That would also remove the need for `array_merge` which copies the array yet again.

That should save some time. Another suggestion would be: Instead of looping through all the days in the entire payment period which could be 30, 60, 90+ etc, You could loop through only the months between $period_start and $period_end and multiply by the days. Your loop reduces from days to months. Pseudo Code:

```
//Find the beginning and end months
$endMonth = getMonth($payment->period_start);
$startMonth = getMonth($payment->period_end);

/*Now for each month do some calculations. Your inner loop drops in
iterations significantly. You'll need some help methods to increase a
month and compare months. I'm writing $month < $endMonth, but that just 
signifies a pseudo calculation. You can't rely on that alone because 
December (12) will not be less than January (01), but your method should 
handle.*/

for($month = $startMonth, $month <= $endMonth, addMonth($month)) {
  $toalDaysInMonth = getDaysInMonth($month); // You can even move this outside of loop as static for the application b/c it won't change (until a leap year)
  
  // If in current month calculate difference between begin and full month to get partial days
  // Partial 1st month
  if($month == $startMonth) {
    $dayDiff = ($daysInMonth - $startDay);
    $byMonth[$month] = ($byMonth[$month] ?? 0) + ($amountPerDay * $dayDiff);
  }
  else if ($month == $endMonth) {  // Partial end month
    // For the end month, you just need how many days into the month
    $byMonth[$month] = ($byMonth[$month] ?? 0) + ($endDay * $amountPerDay);
  }
  else {  // Full month
    $byMonth[$month] = ($byMonth[$month] ?? 0) + ($toalDaysInMonth * $amountPerDay);
  }
}
```

Comment: The DB call is reasonably fast. It takes 3-4 seconds in C# to load ~67k rows.
I agree that your approach would be faster, but it shouldn't make a huge difference on reasonably fast machine? Maybe it would save a second or so?

Comment: When you say "excruciatingly slow" for the entire computation, how long is it taking? Honestly 3-4 full seconds for the DB call seems slow to me for only 67k rows, but not horrible. I think the approach will save more than a second or so; because it is reducing each iteration by hundreds of thousands of rounds. If you even assume an average of 30 days per payment period for 65k payments, my approach reduces iterations to 65k vs. (65k * 30) = 1.950M

Comment: Excruciatingly slow means 1 minute or so in total. I have given up trying to fix this and have moved this to a nighly job.

Comment: Did you give my attempt a try to confirm performance?